# Haskell graph drawing on Windows

Tags: haskell, drawing, graph, plot

I'm using the Haskell platform on Windows and I'd like to write a small program which can draw graphs.  The graph should be exported to any image format (or even PDF).

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

(By graph I mean plot.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By "graph", do you mean the graph theory meaning of graph (nodes and edges) or a plot?

The easiest way to output a graph, in any language, is to pipe [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html) into [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).  Hackage even has a helpful [Data.Graphviz](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/graphviz) package which does some of the low-level work for you, especially if you're already working with the excellent [FGL](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/fgl).

The easiest way to output a plot, in any language, is to pipe *gnuplot script* into [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/).  Again, there's a [Graphics.Gnuplot](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/gnuplot) package on Hackage.

[Graphics.Rendering.Chart](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/Chart) is quite nice; it does a fair amount more than gnuplot.

Actually, you should just look around [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/) and see what best suits your needs...

Comment: Is there a package that works natively on Windows, without requiring GTK and such? Cairo doesn't install on windows from cabal.